# Второе условие цикла игнорируется, в чём ошибка?

Tags: python, while, turtle

```
while life > 0 or scores < 10:
    x_k = kat.xcor()
    y_k = kat.ycor()
    k_toX = random.randint(-100, 100)
    k_toY = random.randint(-100, 100) 
    if x_k + k_toX >= 280 or x_k + k_toX <= -280:
        k_toX = k_toX * (-1)
    if y_k + k_toY >= 250 or y_k + k_toY <= -280:
        k_toY = k_toY * (-1)
    kat.goto(x_k + k_toX, y_k + k_toY)
    if scores >= 1:
        kat.shape('angry_kat.gif')
    if p.distance(kat) < kd and scores >= 1 == True:
        p.shape('d.gif')
        life = life - 1 
        print("XP: " + str(life))
    else:
        p.shape('p.gif')
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter > 15:
       e.hideturtle() 
       e.setposition(random.randint(-300, 300), random.randint(-200, 200))
       e.showturtle()
       counter = 0
    if p.distance(e) < 60 and e.isvisible() == True:
        e.hideturtle()
        scores = scores + 1
        print("Очки:" + str(scores))
    screen.listen()
```

Comment: какое условие у нас второе?

Comment: Начало кода не влезло: while life > 0 or scores < 10:

Comment: печатает life равное 0 и score 10+, а цикл продолжается?

Comment: Да, life > 0 работает, а на scores < 10 цикл не заканчивается

Comment: так у вас стоит или, достаточно, чтоб одно условие выполнилось. ставьте and

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена)

Answer (score 0):

`while life > 0 and scores < 10:`